# Electron Application run on apple silicon ARM64

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, apple-silicon

We are able to ran the Electron desktop application by  using electron-builder along with dmg on X64.If we want to run same application on **apple silicon(ARM64)**, We installed following dependancies(X64)
1 Xcode 12 and upgrade Mac to Bix sur.
2 "npm install electron@11.0.0-beta.1"
3 node-gyp(7.1.2)

but, found below errors:

**"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of null"**

Also while building and packaging the application we want to add extraFiles.
Kindly suggest if any solution.

Also read about **electron-packager**,but How can we add extra files using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve your error but I can suggest to you to install the latest electron release and not a beta version. If you think the beta can be the best way to use with an apple silicon (I don't now if the latest beta is compiled for it) you can try it equally, because macOS will compile electron for you... (it can takes about 20 seconds to compile).

Comment: Yes . I already tried latest electron version.but got the same error.